# Phonegap GaPlugin refusing connection

Tags: javascript, android, google-analytics, cordova

So I installed the plugin for phonegap to run google analytics. I set it up using plugman, no issues. However I am unable to establish a connection to google analytics.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        console.log('device ready');
        config.gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
        config.gaPlugin.init(console.log('ga plugin inititalized'), console.log('ga plugin failed'), config.analyticsCode, 1);
    }, false);
```

And Instead of getting a connection back I get one response of

```
W/GAV2(12581): Thread[WebViewCoreThread,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
```

I thought the init function was the initialize? However as I set it every 5 seconds the connection gets refused.

```
W/GAV2(12581): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Connection to https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
W/GAV2(12581): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
```

I have no idea what to do next, I've seen reference of needing to modify the errorhandling calls to not look for an https request, but I would like to hope its just an error in my code or a configuration error. Anyone have insight?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code which works with GAPlugin

```
gaInit: function() {
    gaPlugin.init(gaSuccessConnect, gaFail, "UA-XXXXXX-3", 10);
},

gaSuccess: function() {
    console.log('Successfully connected to Google Analytics');
},

gaSuccessConnect: function() {
    console.log('Successfully initiated connection to Google Analytics');
    gaTrackPage();
},

gaFail: function() {
    console.warn("Failed to connect to Google Analytics");
},

gaTrackPage: function() {
    gaPlugin.trackPage(gaSuccess, gaFail, "index.html");
    console.log('Tracking index');
},

gaTrackPageView: function(page) {
    var index = "index.html";
    var trackpage = index.concat(page);
    console.log('Tracking ' + page);
    gaPlugin.trackPage(gaSuccess, gaFail, trackpage);
},
```

and call gaInit from onDeviceReady.